# Issue on Pushing files to GIT version control from delphi code

Tags: git, delphi, github

i was trying to commit files in to GIT and then push them to GIT HUB from delphi code.

Please see below code:

i am getting access violation at :

git_remote_connect(remote,GIT_DIR_PUSH); 
git_remote_pushspec(remote);

```
uses uGitForDelphi;

procedure TfrmMain.CommitClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   repo: Pgit_repository;
   commit: Pgit_commit;
   tree_id, parent_id, commit_id: git_oid;
   author, committer: Pgit_signature;
   author1, committer1: Pgit_signature;
   parent: Pgit_commit;
   tree: Pgit_tree;
   index: Pgit_index;
   head, branch: Pgit_reference;
   remote: Pgit_remote;
   const
   branch_name: PAnsiChar = 'refs/heads/master';
begin

   git_repository_open(repo, REPOSITORY_FOLDER);

   git_oid_fromstr(@tree_id, tree_oid);


   git_oid_fromstr(@parent_id, PAnsiChar(commit_ids[4]));


   git_reference_lookup(head, repo, 'HEAD');
   git_reference_set_target(head, branch_name);

   git_repository_index(index, repo);
   git_index_entrycount(index);
   git_index_add(index, 'TestingNewfile.txt', 0);

   //* create signatures */
   git_signature_new(committer, COMMITTER_NAME, COMMITTER_EMAIL, 123456789, 60));
   git_signature_new(author, COMMITTER_NAME, COMMITTER_EMAIL, 987654321, 90));

  git_commit_create_v(
      @commit_id, //* out id */
      repo,
      'Head', //* do not update the HEAD */
      author,
      committer,
      nil,
      COMMIT_MESSAGE,
      tree,
      1, parent));

   git_commit_lookup(commit, repo, @commit_id));

   //* Check attributes were set correctly */
   author1 := git_commit_author(commit);

    committer1 := git_commit_committer(commit);

   *git_remote_new(remote,repo, 'https://github.com/iambasiljoy/Jungle', 'Jungle');
   git_remote_connect(remote,GIT_DIR_PUSH);
   (git_remote_pushspec(remote));
 //  git_commit_free(commit);
//   git_repository_free(repo);*
end;
```

i am getting access violation on below lines.

git_remote_connect(remote,GIT_DIR_PUSH);
git_remote_pushspec(remote);

Could any one tell me what i am missing here and how to connect github and push some files there from code.

Thanks
Bjoy

Comment: I deleted my answer because it seems that the code you are actually using is very different from that in the question. And it seems that you are looking for more than just an explanation of why you get the AV. I don't think I can provide that.

Comment: sorry you misunderstood that. i was replying your comment -"the dll does not contain the git_remore_new function. if i execute the code " git_remote_new := Bind('git_remote_new', '20');" then i am not getting any exception so that shows the dll contain that function. Yes this code is not included in my question because it is already executed initially when i load the dll. sorry about that.